# Routing public IP addresses to customers in a WISP setup

Tags: routing, nat, pfsense, ubiquiti, ubiquiti-edgerouter

We have a fibre leaseline with a /29 range for our pfSense WAN port

`61.179.145.40/29`

So the WAN of our pfSense box is `61.179.145.42` with a gateway of `61.179.145.41`.

Our ISP has also routed `61.179.144.128/25` with a next-hop of `61.179.145.42` (our pfSense box).

The LAN of our pfSense box is `10.0.0.1/19`. From the LAN of our pfSense box we go to a managed Edgeswitch which has 6x Ubiquiti Rocket's attached. Each rocket has an IP in the `10.0.0.0/19` range and the wireless clients (also Ubiquiti gear) get an IP of `10.0.0.0/19`. We can then set 1:1 NAT's to each of our clients IP addresses.

For example, Client 1:

[image: Client 1 setup]

We set up a 1:1 NAT rule in pfSense to assign `61.179.144.160` to `10.0.0.16`. When we go to whatismyip.com on `10.0.0.16`, it works fine. However I am not happy with this setup. I would rather directly assign a subnetted range of our routed range directly to the customer. So when the customer plugs in their equipment to our termination, they enter their external IP, subnet and gateway (an interface defined on an interface on pfSense, or even a router we supply them for them to connect to?).

We have managed this scenario by using VLAN's in a cabled environment simply by disabling NAT on pfSense.

Hope this makes sense.